# Question about using a transform to solve Laplace's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

I want to solve $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}= 0$
subject to $u(0,y)=A$ for $0<y<\pi$, and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} |_{y=0}= 0 $,
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} |_{y=\pi}=Be^{-x} $, $x>0$. I feel like there's not enough information for me to solve this problem, I am trying to use a Laplace transform in $x$. What am I missing? Thanks four your help!

Comment: Can you find $u(x,0)$ and $u(x,\pi)$ from the boundaries conditions ?

Comment: Can you show us your progress?